# Prevent div from taking the place of another div

Tags: css, html

I have two `div` elements within a container, one `div` positioned *under* the first `div`. I also have a JS function running that will grab the first `div`, and center it on the screen for display purpose. The JS function will then re position the first `div` back in its place. The problem is, the second `div` moves up to take the first `div`'s place when it moves out, and they overlap when the first `div` moves back into place. How do I prevent the second `div` from moving up and taking the first `div`'s place?

Comment: Show your related css and markup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you're setting `position: absolute` on the `div` you're moving?

In that case, use `position: relative` instead and that `div` will still reserve its original space in the document.

Comment: Top and left is specified to move it. I don't think that would work.

Comment: @Da General: See http://jsfiddle.net/RichieHindle/AXU6m/ for a working (albeit not interactive) example.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can capture the contents of the container div in a var 'before' centering the first one and when you need to go back to the way things were, you could replace the initial contents back

```
var initialHtml = $(containerDiv).html()
//center the first div
//after the purpose of centering is achieved
$(containerDiv).html(initialHtml)
```

Comment: So wait, what exactly would this be doing?

Comment: It would just re-use the HTML snippet that had the elements placed correctly in the first place.